# php code does not work with an German ä,ü,ö

Tags: php, mysql, diacritics

In the following code, there two variables getting from a mysql database and they are compared with the content of several txt files and the txt file containing the variables is output to my page. Folds also wonderful.
Now here are my two problems.
In addition to the content, the code also indicates the path of the txt file and I do not know how I can hide it. Have spent here already a few hours with trying, but unfortunately without result.

Secondly, the variable $title already contains an ä, ö, or ü.
Then the code does not work anymore!

Could someone help me please?

```
<?php
/**
 * Searches for lines matching all regexp patterns.
 *
 * @param string $dir Path to directory with text files
 * @param array $patterns AWK patterns without regexp markers ('/')
 * @return array Files matching all patterns
 * @throws InvalidArgumentException
 */
function grepDir($dir, array $patterns, callable $callback) {
  if (!$patterns) {
    throw new InvalidArgumentException("Invalid patterns");
  }

  // Build command as awk '/pattern1/ && /pattern2/ && ... path-to-file'
  $awk_script = '/' . implode('/ && /', $patterns) . '/';
  $awk_script = escapeshellarg($awk_script);
  $command_format = "awk $awk_script %s";

  try {
    $it = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($dir));

    $it->rewind();
    while ($it->valid()) {
      if (!$it->isDot()) {
        $file_path = $it->key();
        $command = sprintf($command_format, $file_path);
        $output = null;
        exec($command, $output, $exit_status);

        if ($exit_status) {
          trigger_error("Command failed: $command");
          continue;
        }

        if ($output) {
          $callback($file_path, $output);
        }
      }

      $it->next();
    }
  } catch (Exception $e) {
    trigger_error($e->getMessage());
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
$title = $this->item->title;
$ergebnis = $extraField->value;
$dir = './webtt_alt/daten';
$patterns = [ $title , $ergebnis ];
grepDir($dir, $patterns, function ($file_path, array $output) {
  printf("%s\n\n%s\n\n", $file_path, implode(PHP_EOL, $output));
});
?>
```